# Which callback to apply with SWA: AverageModelCheckpoint or ModelCheckpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, callback, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to understand the difference in using SWA ([Tensorflow addons implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/SWA)) with and without callbacks. So, I have two implementations and both of them work fine. But, I am not sure about the difference between the two. The first is without swa callback:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
opt = tfa.optimizers.SWA(optimizer, start_averaging=start_epoch,
                   average_period=1, lr=0.005)
model.compile(loss=lossFunction, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
# simple early stopping
es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20)
mc = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpointFilePath, monitor='val_accuracy',
                     mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(valX, valy),
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs, verbose=0, callbacks=[es, mc])
```

The second one is the same, except it has an extra callback:

```
swa = tfa.callbacks.AverageModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpointFilePath,
                                                    update_weights=True)
```

And when swa callback is added, the last line changes as follows:

```
history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(valX, valy),
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs, verbose=0, callbacks=[es, mc, swa])
```

My question is what is the difference between these two implementations? And if there is any, which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

The `ModelCheckpoint` callback let's you save a model or it's weights at some interval. This is useful if you want to **later load the weights** to continue the training from a state saved.

However, with `ModelCheckpoint` you can not save moving average weights at some interval. That is, Model Average Optimizers require a custom callback to save the weights. With `AverageModelCheckpoint` you can save the weights and optionally assign this averaged weights to the model.